# PHP: Send more than article in one email

Tags: php, email

I have a table named 'an_posts' and a column inside the table named 'post_title'. I need to send an email to user when i select more than 'post_title'. But the code below is only send one 'post_title'. Why is that happened and what I have to add in the code so that the email send will retrieve two or more data from database ?

```
if($_GET["action"] == 'sendpostnewsletter')
    {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $_POST["post_id"];
        $emailtosender = $_POST["emailtosender"];
        $subjecttitle = $_POST["subjecttitle"];
        $sql = "select * from an_posts where post_type = 'post' and post_status = 'publish' and ID in ($post_id)";
        $formssql = mysql_query($sql);
            while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($formssql) ) 
            {
                $message = '
                <div align="center"><h3>'.$row['post_title'].'</h3></div>
                <br />
                <div style="text-align:justify; font-size:16px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight:bold">
                '.$row['post_content'].'
                </div>';
            }

        $message .= "<hr />";
        $headers = "From: Newsletter <list@domainname.com>" . "\n" ;
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\n";
        wp_mail( $emailtosender , $subjecttitle , $message, $headers );
        $result='<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong><h5>done</h5></strong></p></div>';
        echo $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the content of message each loop. Instead append to it:

```
//initialize outside the loop
$message='';
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($formssql) ) 
{
    //then append - notice the dot .=
    $message .= '
    ...
```